# TSQL Dynamic Where

Tags: t-sql, dynamic, where-clause, clause

I would like to do something ike this.

```
declare @var1 as integer

Select * from table name 
where id
If @var1 = 1 then
 21 
elseif  @var1 = 2
 <>21
```

All I would like to know is if this is possible. The only thing that needs to change is the comparison operator.

Answer (score 3):

```
where ( @var1 = 1 and id = 21) or (@var1 = 2 and id <> 21)
```